# Angular mat-button-toggle-group limit number of displayed characters and add hint

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, angular-material

Is is possible to limit the number of characters of the value displayed on the mat-button-toggle elements from a mat-button-toggle-group?
The component.html file:

```
...
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [value] = "selectedValue">
 <mat-button-toggle  *ngFor="let item of toggleOptions;" (change)="onChange($event)" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
...
```

The texts on the mat-button can be very long, I would like to limit them to 10 characters and show the full text as hint. How can this be realized?
The component.ts file:

```
...
  toggleOptions: Array<String> = ["Option 12345678900987654321", "Option 55"];
...
```

Comment: You can give the `mat-button-toggle` a width and then use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to trunctate the value. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nae4pe?file=src/app/app.component.css) to demonstrate this approach. Note that the component styles must be global in order to change material styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in component to truncate the string if length exceed 10 and use [mat tool tip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) to show hint on hover.Show the code will be. **Ts**

```
 truncateVal(val:string){
    return val?.length > 10 ? val.substring(0,10)+'...' : val;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [value]="selectedValue">
  <mat-button-toggle
    [matTooltip]="item"
    *ngFor="let item of toggleOptions"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    [value]="item"
    >{{ truncateVal(item) }}</mat-button-toggle
  >
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-toggle-group-8p8rpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Is it possible to set all mat-button-toggle items to the same width (lets say 10)? For instance also the ones with shorter values, like toggleOptions: Array<String> = ["Option 12345678900987654321", "Option 55", "Opt2"];

Comment: just add a class to you mat-button and then change width with  css like https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-toggle-group-8p8rpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this for `mat-button-toggle`:

```css
button {
    height: 21px;
    max-width: 10ch;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello World!</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to force all buttons to same width, independently of the text length?

Comment: @RickyTad this is an example for your problem, just set a class for `mat-button-toggle` :))